# how to make auto Resize

Tags: javascript, jquery

let say there are three column in a container, if i minimize the width of any element then  adjacent element should cover the area by maximize it's width.  [my live example on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sadrana/SrJfu/6/)
What i want :
***1. if any element resize (minimize or maximize) then adjacent element should auto adjust the width

 2.container has fix size and should not be change the dimension

3. element must be auto fit inside the container***
is there any way to use handler e.g. jQuery uses in it's layout [ui-resizable-handle](http://layout.jquery-dev.net/demos/layout_inside_dialog.html)

```
   <div id = "container">
      <div id = "element1"> </div>
      <div id = "element2"> </div>
      <div id = "element3"> </div>
    </div>


    #element1 {width:30%; height:100;}
    #element2 {width:40%; height:100;}
    #element3 {width:30%; height:100;}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest, remove padding, margin, and border in #element1, 2, 3.

Maybe this will help.

```
$(function() {

    var startwidth = 0;
    var containerwidth = $('#container').width();

    $('.resize').resizable({
        containment:'#container',
        start: function(){
            startwidth = $(this).width() / containerwidth;
        },
        stop: function(event, ui){
            var nsiblings = $(this).siblings().size();
            var delta = ($(this).width() / containerwidth  - startwidth);
            $(this).siblings().each(function(){
                var siblingswidth = ($(this).width() / containerwidth - delta / nsiblings) * containerwidth;
                $(this).width( siblingswidth );
            });
            var totalwidth = 0;
            $('#container').children().each(function(){
                totalwidth = totalwidth + $(this).width();
            });
            if(totalwidth > containerwidth){
                $(this).width($(this).width() - (totalwidth - containerwidth));
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks raymond, I just tried myself & about to resolve but you gave me better idea. please take a look of my sol'n http://jsfiddle.net/pankajkits/SrJfu/44/

Comment: sorry, i didn't read your question carefully. you only want to resize adjacent element, right? i've updated your [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/raymondralibi/X2bXY/1/).

Comment: Thank you so much. can you please do me a favor? you resoved the issue but only problem i am getting when i resize then one div just goes outside (overflow) of it's parent so how can i fix this. thanks again...

Comment: I can't see any problem in my previous fiddle. Just stick with my suggestion: remove padding, margin, and border in #element1, 2, 3 or children of `#container`. Can't you update your fiddle, so i can see the issue.

Comment: there is not any error but during the resize i found div overflows but when i stop, it auto-fits into container. as we used "start" & "stop". What i want to fix? overflow during the resize. finally it doesn't have any kind of error except overflow during resizing.  pls check your own solution and you'll see when we resize divs are overflowing. thanks...